# Finding details on .NET Framework bugs

Tags: .net

I'm reading the code of `Control.Async` (file `control.fs`) from F# library and there is the following comment:

```
// See bug 370350; this logic is incorrect from the perspective of how SynchronizationContext is meant to work,
// but the logic works for mainline scenarios (WinForms/WPF/ASP.NET) and we won't change it again.
```

I wonder where can I find details about bug 370350 or more generally about .NET Framework bugs?

Comment: That bug number falls in the range of bugs that are quoted in other .NET Framework source code files.  DevDiv's internal bug database is not publicly accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately that's not something I hoped for. (If you want to, you can turn the comment into an answer and I'll accept it.)